# VBA - Descending Sort Works Only When Stepping Through Code

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm trying to sort a column in descending order. The code works just fine when I step through it, but when the macro is run in full, the data is not sorted. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Here's the bit of code:

```
Dim temp_str as String
Dim lrow as Long
Dim DOX_Net_Lvl_Col_Loc as Long
Dim DOX_ws as WorkSheet
Set DOX_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DOX")

' Sort Netting Level in descending order
With DOX_ws
    .Activate
    temp_str = ConvertToLetter(DOX_Net_Lvl_Col_Loc)
    .Range(temp_str & "1:" & temp_str & lrow).Sort _
       Key1:=.Range(temp_str & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending
End With

Function ConvertToLetter(ColNo As Long) As String
    ConvertToLetter = Split(Cells(, ColNo).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Obviously, this is just a snippet of the overall code. I've already confirmed that `lrow` and `temp_str` are correctly calculated. Also, when testing the code, I confirmed that `.Range(temp_str & "1:" & temp_str & lrow).Select` grabs the full range I want to sort. What could prevent the code from working during a full run of the macro?

To give a bit more context, the sub (let's call it "DOX") to populate the file/sort the column is only called from a different sub (let's call it "Master"). When I run the DOX sub by itself, the sort works perfectly. I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I tested the code and runs fine (with debugger and ran alone).The only thing that I can think about is if, by some random reason, there are leftovers from another sub (since you say it's called). An autofilter that may be interfering (set .AutoFilterMode = False after .Activate DOX_ws sheet) , or sheet protection for filter.

Comment: Try qualifying the `cells` getting `split` in `ConvertToLetter`?

Comment: No luck on `.AutoFilterMode = False`, still unsorted when running the Master sub. The `ConvertToLetter` function is working just fine - it returns what is expected ("K" in this case).

Comment: Is there any "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" ruling?

Comment: I do have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the MASTER sub which calls the DOX sub. That shouldn't matter though, right?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution. If I change the range to be `.Range("A1:" & temp_str & lrow).Sort`, then it works. I guess it needed the whole range of the data to perform the sort; just giving it the column wasn't enough, evidently.